# How do I view "friends of friends" for my RealID friends?

Tags: diablo-iii

In World of Warcraft, you could view the friends of your RealID friends and send them a friend request.

Where is that option in Diablo 3?

Answer (score 1):

Alas, at the moment that feature is not in Diablo 3.

You *could* go log in to World of Warcraft and do it instead.